# Add metadata value only to doc page

Tags: html, docbook

I have a need to know which page is the toc page in our html output from our Solr index. I would like to add a metadata entry that identifies the output as the toc. Everything that I have tried puts the value in all pages. We are using docbook 4.5, and I am very new to xslt. Any pointers to the right direction would be a big help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think the DocBook XSL stylesheets provide any pretty way to do this, so here’s an ugly hack:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:import
    href="/usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl/html/chunk.xsl"/>
  <xsl:template name="head.content.generator">
    <xsl:param name="node" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="not(parent::*)">
      <meta name="TOC" content="This is the TOC"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <meta name="generator" content="DocBook {$DistroTitle} V{$VERSION}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You’d need to put that in a file named `docbook-custom.xsl` and call that from your XSLT engine:

```
xsltproc docbook-custom.xsl BOOK.xml
```

Within the `docbook-custom.xsl` “customization layer” file, you need to set the `href` value of the `xsl:import` element to wherever you actually have the DocBook XSL stylesheets installed.

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomMethods.html#CustomizationLayer has general details.

Of course instead of the `<meta name="TOC" content="This is the TOC"/>` in the stylesheet above, you want to change that to whatever the actual `meta` element is that you want to add.

This customization layer customizes the `head.content.generator` template to cause it to take whatever you actually set as your custom `meta` element, and inject that just before the `meta name="generator"` element that the stock DocBook stylesheets themselves output.

The `<xsl:if test="not(parent::*)">…</xsl:if>` causes the stylesheets to output your custom `meta` element only in the first output HTML “chunk”, which by default is named `index.html` and which by default is the same file the TOC is included in.